# Entity detection from sentences differ in training and testing sentences

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, api-ai

Entity detection is working fine while training the phrases i.e the words of interest (entities) are highlighted when the sentence is being added as a training sample, but when the same sentence is tested , the entities are not selected.

[image]
[image]
If we look at example attached, the entity

> price of property

was automatically selected  during training but was empty/not detected during the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the value / entry  "2 crores" is not duplicated in "price of property" entity.

Comment: There are no duplications in that entity

Comment: Please check duplicates in other entities as well. As such kind of problem exist if there is same value duplicated in multiple places

Answer (score 0):

In order for a reference value to be matched, it needs to be included as a synonym itself. When you first enter a reference value, it will be automatically added as a synonym. If for some reason this is removed, make sure to add the original value as a synonym so it can be matched.

[image: Example]